# Custom Error Page for Apache

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

My .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/forbidden/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

<Directory /server>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 500 /server/error500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /server/error404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /server/error404.html
ErrorDocument 402 /subscription_info.html
```

---

All my error pages are in htdocs/server/error***.html

But Apache shows its generic error page.

Comment: Mention your requirement clearly..

Answer (score 0):

ErrorDocument 404 http://site.com/error.php as your recovery.